# Can't disable vignette build when using devtools

Tags: r, r-devtools

When running

```
==> devtools::check(args = c('--no-build-vignettes','--no-vignettes'))
```

from RStudio the vignettes are still being build:

```
...
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  installing the package to build vignettes (1.4s)
   creating vignettes ...
```

I configured the Build tools according to:
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options

Should including

```
--no-vignettes do not run R code in vignettes
--no-build-vignettes do not build vignette outputs
```

not disable the vignette build?

Comment: `?devtools::check` ... have you tried simply  `devtools::check(vignettes = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `build_args`, which is for arguments passed while building the package, not `args` which is for arguments passed while checking.